# jQuery load() function not working like expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've a custom function which should refresh a div. Inside this div there is a PHP shortcode which should be refreshed when I call the function. This works good but the problem is when the div gets initially:

The jQuery function:

```
jQuery('.container').load(document.URL + ' .container');
```

The PHP:

```
<div class="container">
    <?php echo do_shortcode( '[wpfd id="' . $id . '"]' ); ?>
</div>
```

How it looks when I load it initially with my load function:

[image]

How it should looks like (after refreshing the whole site):

[image]

My plan was to build my own ajax loading to control the content but this don't looks like expected. Whats wrong with my code?

Comment: looks like you do not have the css

Comment: Thats right.. If you load a html page into a div you need to use inline styling. If the styling is in the header you need to make sure you have all the styling, and classes..

Comment: @bothofyou you were so right, let me check a thing

Comment: Thanks for bringing me on the right way. The plugin css file is named style.css too but has its own content and gets loaded after site refresh and content is visible. Moved it now to my functions.php thanks for giving me this little brain push :D

Comment: You can give my answer a vote. This will declare my official dumbness. Thanks a lot for helping me lol!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

The plugins CSS file is named style.css too and that's why I thought everything is cool but it has its own content and gets loaded after site refresh and content is visible. When the content isn't loaded, the CSS file is not loaded too (which is stupid and static but ok):

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'file_download', content_url() . '/plugins/wp-file-download/app/site/themes/wpfd-default/css/style.css' );
```